# How to get data from child to parent entity framework core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6

I have two table like this -

```
public class Job
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedTime { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime LastEdit { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string  Explanation { get; set; }
    public string PhotoString { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

and company -

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PhotoString { get; set; }

    public bool isActive { get; set; } = true;

    public int AppUserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
    public List<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}
```

I only want to get `AppUserId` from `Company` and all `Jobs` from every `Company`. I tried this and it gave me error.

```
using var context = new SocialWorldDbContext();
return await context.Jobs.Where(I => I.isActive == true && I.Company.isActive).Include(I=>I.Company.AppUserId).ToListAsync();
```

So my question is there any way I can get this data from parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` adds whole entities to the output.  To add just one property use `Select`, something like

```
 context.Jobs
        .Where(I => I.isActive == true && I.Company.isActive)
        .Select(e => new {Job=e, CompanyAppUserId = e.Company.AppUserId})
        .ToListAsync();
```